# Passing a placeholder text using django-filter and different views

Tags: django, placeholder, django-filter

I have a model:

```
class Movie (models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Kategoria filmu', default= 'unassigned', null=False, choices=category_choices)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Źródło filmu', default= 'unassigned', null=False, choices=source_choices)
    promotion = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='PROMOCJA FILMU')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Nazwa influencera')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Nazwa filmu')
    content = models.TextField(max_length=10000, verbose_name='HTML EMBEDED do filmu')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    youtube_url = models.URLField(blank=True, max_length=300)
    tiktok_url = models.URLField(blank=True, max_length=300)
    insta_url = models.URLField(blank=True, max_length=300)
```

I am passing it to the view with djnago-filter with different category choice:

views.py:

```
#HotTop View
class HotTopView (FilterView):
    model = Movie
    template_name = 'pages/hot_top.html'
    filterset_class = MovieFilter 
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self):
        category_qs = self.model.objects.filter(category="HOT-TOP")
        return category_qs.order_by('-date_posted')

#Odkrycia View
class OdkryciaView (FilterView):
    model = Movie
    template_name = 'pages/odkrycia.html'
    filterset_class = MovieFilter
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self):
        category_qs = self.model.objects.filter(category="ODKRYCIA")
        return category_qs.order_by('-date_posted')
```

and my filters.py:

```
class MovieFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    author = django_filters.CharFilter(label='', lookup_expr='contains',  widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Search'}))
    
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ['author']
```

The question is how can i change placeholder of my serach form depending on the view (HotTop or Odkrycia). I want it to be - when i am in HotTop View -> *Search in Hot Top* and when i am in Odkrycia - > *Search in Odkrycia*

Answer (score 0):

I think you could pass an argument

```
class MovieFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    author = django_filters.CharFilter(label='', lookup_expr='contains',  widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Search'}))
    
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ['author']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        placeholder = kwargs.pop('placeholder', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if placeholder :
            self.fields['author'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': f'Search in {placeholder}'})
```

and then in the views you can use `get_filterset_kwargs` method to pass the view name.

```
#HotTop View
class HotTopView(FilterView):
    ...
    def get_filterset_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(HotTopView, self).get_filterset_kwargs()           
        kwargs['placeholder'] = "Hot Top"           
        return kwargs
    ...
```

the other view:

```
#Odkrycia View
class OdkryciaView(FilterView):
    ...
    def get_filterset_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(OdkryciaView, self).get_filterset_kwargs()           
        kwargs['placeholder'] = "Odkrycia"           
        return kwargs
    ...
```

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Tnaks for a reply, it almost works but when i try to call HotTopView i get:

get_filterset_kwargs() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/hot-top/
Django Version: 3.2.8
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
get_filterset_kwargs() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given